# How to avoid error of stdio.h while using a clang checker on a file which includes stdio.h file

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I have implemented a checker in clang. I have compiled it and now i am using it to check on a c file which includes stdio.h file. I am giving below command to run the checker :
    clang -cc1 -analyze -analyzer-checker=alpha.core.FuncPrototype funcprototypetest.c

I am getting below error :
    funcprototypetest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found

```
#include <stdio.h>
     ^
```

Can anybody help me with a proper way to handle this error.When i compile the funcprototype.c file independently with gcc, it gets compiled. So i am not getting what can be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't find "#include <stdio.h>" your c compiler is probably broken.

Comment: Thanks Elliott. I found that stdio.h file is present in the directory /usr/include/ . Even if i give absolute path like #include "/usr/include/stdio.h" it gives error for other files like stddef.g and many others which are included in stdio.h. So can we still say that probable cause is the broken compiler or is there anything that you think of?

Answer (score 1):

Answer found here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/37462

You mast use

```
clang --analyze -Xclang -analyzer-checker=alpha.core.FuncPrototype funcprototypetest.c
```

instead

```
clang -cc1 -analyze -analyzer-checker=alpha.core.FuncPrototype funcprototypetest.c
```